# Returning the sum of all multiples of a number up to 1000

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I've been learning Python and in order to put my skills to the test, I created a simple program that returns the sum of all of the multiples of number `num` up to 1000.

```
def get_multiple_sum(num):
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, 1001):
        if i % num == 0:
            sum += i
        else:
            continue
    return sum
```

Is this the fastest way to do this? I'm always looking for ways to make my code more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` takes an optional third argument, which is the step size for the sequence. For example:

```
range(0, 10, 3) # Returns [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Python also has a built-in `sum` function that adds up all the numbers in an array, so you could refactor your code to look like this:

```
def get_multiple_sum(num):
    return sum(range(0, 1000, num))
```

Performance-wise, this should be much faster, as it doesn't perform 1000 remainder operations and uses a library function which may be optimized by the interpreter.

Comment: I think for the correct answer, that `1` should be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_multiple_sum(num):
    sum = 0
    i = 0
```

This line has no effect. You replace i in the next line

```
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        if i % num == 0:
            sum += i
        else:
            continue
```

Continue just before the end of a loop has no effect

```
    return sum
```

But as Na7coldwater points out, you can do the whole thing as a quick summation. However, you should be able to figure out a formula for the result of the summation, see Wikipedia which has a list of such formulas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation. Then you can avoid doing a loop at all.

Comment: It is hard to beat an O(1) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to sum the multiples of `num 1001/num` times, which is why I choose `n = 1001/num`. As others have mentioned, summations can be transformed in \$O(1)\$ operations:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{1001/\text{num}} i * \text{num} = k \sum_{i=1}^{1001/\text{num}} = \text{num} * \frac{n * (n + 1)}{2}
$$

Your code then becomes:

```
def get_multiple_sum(num):
    n = 1001/num
    return num * n * (n+1)/2
```